# Is there a way to use a working HTML page as an Angular 5/6 component?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, angular5

We are undergoing an project in Angular 5/6 where we get prebuilt HTML pages, that use jQuery, gridstack.js and CSS for UI, that we'll implement as components. Assuming it's not possible to rewrite all the jQuery and JS code in Angular, is there any way to run the jQuery code provided in the  tag directly in Angular?

I have already tried importing jQuery as:

```
import $ from 'jQuery';
```

Here is a sample of the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
    $('.grid-stack').gridstack({
      width: 12
    });
    $(".accordion-toggle").click(function () {
      $(this).toggleClass("activu");
      $(".accordion-toggle").not(this).removeClass("activu");
    })
    var options = {
      float: true
    };
    $('.grid-stack').gridstack(options);
</script>
```

Comment: >Assuming it's not possible to rewrite all the jQuery and JS code in Angular - it is, and you probably should. You can just use jQuery (and GridStack) in your angular code. it will even become less messy if you properly use components.

Comment: The problem is my internship project has a time constrain and the UI designers have included hundreds of JS, jQuery and CSS files, converting them to angular would take up atleast a week

Comment: Don't mix angular and jquery/js, It'll create lots of problems. If you want, go for angular.js that is also not good practice but it'll save time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible and could be a good intermediate step on a migration path.

I am working on a project right now where we have a JQuery-based app. It has a lot of CSS and HTML code inside the JS code to handle state changes and change content and styling accordingly. It is relatively messy.

We took a number of steps of migrating to Angular, with the first being what you are describing. It definitely already helped gain an overview of the code base and structure the code in a much more maintainable way than it was before.

1. **I took the HTML and broke it down into Angular components**. For this step, we just left the JQuery code in the main AppComponent TS file. You can simply use JQuery in Angular TS files with a `declare const $: any;`.
2. I broke down the the JQuery code and **migrated everything that was template related** (e.g. changing parts of the DOM tree based on events/state) into the Angular HTML files.
3. I took the one large CSS file and **moved the CSS rules to the individual components**.
4. I went through the entire remaining **JQuery code** and piece by piece migrated it **to proper Angular code**.

It proved to be a viable strategy. We were first considering re-writing the entire project, but like this we always had a running version, could continuously run UI tests against it and piece by piece migrate.

All of that is to say: I would not see a JQuery/Angular mix as a final solution, but it can be a good migration strategy.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery in your angular project. Normally jQuery based DOM manipulation is not the standard way for angular but in some cases we have to jQuery plugins for certain features.

Steps:

1. Import jQuery script in your index.html

   `<script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>`
2. Import your plugin css/js in `.angular-cli.json` inside styles and scripts arrays
3. Inside the component where you want to use it , declare jQuery.

   `declare var $ : any;`
4. Use in directly in your component. If plugin needs to be initialised , you can do it inside `ngOnInit`